# How to design D-PAD keybord in android?

Tags: android, d-pad

i want to design D-PAD keyboard in android .I see  user configuration in android. i don't know how to use it.
give some code

Comment: Could you clarify a bit, what sort of application, what you are considered so far, etc?

Comment: just want to design a D-PAD,where each key perform different operation.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about exactly what you need, what you have tried so far, and where you got stuck.  Low quality questions tend to get closed.

Comment: what I want to do is to add 4 buttons on the screen (LIKE D-PAD) and these buttons should different operation With a clickListener and onClick() (or touchListener and onTouch())

Comment: Have you seen the buttons examples in the api demos of the samples/ directory of the SDK?

Comment: want to design Virtual D-pad application.but i did not any example for that

Comment: Where in the process of evolving the simple button demos into your virtual D-pad did you get stuck?

Comment: Use this it may help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561251/dpad-is-disabled-in-emulator

Answer (score 5):

Don't invent the wheel from scratch again, juse use andengine:

http://www.andengine.org/blog/2010/07/andengine-on-screen-controls/

and load everything necessary in the `onLoadScene()`

```
@Override
        public Scene onLoadScene() {
                this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

                final Scene scene = new Scene();
                scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

                final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
                final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
                final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
                final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(face);
                face.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

                scene.attachChild(face);

                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl = new DigitalOnScreenControl(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.mCamera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, new IOnScreenControlListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
                                physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * 100, pValueY * 100);
                        }
                });
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
                this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

                scene.setChildScene(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);

                return scene;
        }
```