# D'pad Is disabled in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, d-pad

I am using android sdk 4.0.3 ,I have created an Emulator of it.
Now I have a problem that the emulator is showing the Disabled 
DPAD Buttons .I have set up the Hardware keyboard present and display skin with buttons option in configuration.

So i just want to enable the Dpad Buttons on emulator
[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Every emulated device is based on a more or less real device, which you chose as '4.0" WVGA (480x800:hdpi)' this doesnt only concern the resolution of your emulated device bur also its hardware features. In the main screen of the avd-manager enter the tab that says device definitions. there you can edit your chosen device and you will find the dpad under input.

Comment: Also note that while devices like the Nexus One (with a trackball) had the Dpad enabled in the emulator as a work around, now the emulator has an actual trackball emulation. Press `del` and move/click the mouse.

Answer (score 25):

This sounds crazy, but it worked for me:

1. Launch a fresh emulator from the Android Virtual Device(AVD) Manager.
   *Note:* "DO NOT START THE DEVICE".
2. Find the configuration file, something like: `~/.android/avd/XXXX.avd/config.ini`
   Notice that this directory has only one `INI` file.
3. Edit `config.ini`:
   change  `hw.dPad=no` to  `hw.dPad=yes`
4. The AVD Manager will still show `dPad=no` when you click on Details.  It appears to not catch on until the virtual device is started.  (Clumsy?  yes)
5. Start the device.  It should show DPAD without the complaint about it not being there.
6. The DETAILS button in AVD Manager should also show `hw.dPad=yes`

I ran into this while trying to bring up the "Snake" demo.  It failed to run, asking to press the UP key -- and the pad didn't respond!  After getting DPAD set, the demo can be controlled through the pad.

This appears to be a bug in the AVD Manager.  If you get dPad set to 'yes', it can be set to 'no' through the AVD Manager.  But changing 'no' to 'yes' requires the above workaround.

Answer (score 14):

The virtual device folder has a config file , just like my Mac OS X and a VM(A17) :

`~/.android/avd/A17.avd/config.ini`

change

```
hw.dPad=no
```

to

```
hw.dPad=yes
```

Comment: It was a combination of this and Subramanaian's answer that worked for me. Only changing one value didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution in a different file. I am using SDK version revision 20.

1. Create a fresh AVD from you AVD manager.
2. There is no option in AVD manager to enable DPAD. I tried even by clicking `Edit`.
3. Go to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.android\avd\YOUR_AVD_NAME` folder
4. Open **hardware-qemu.ini** file. Here you will get all hw config details.
5. There you will find ***hw.dPad = no***; Change it to ***hw.dPad = yes*** and save the file
6. Restart your AVD and Voila !!! DPAD is now enabled in Emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `config.ini` as

```
hw.dPad=no --> hw.dPad=yes
```

.
Clone Device Definitions with enable keyboard

```
Enable Input -> Keyboard.
```

For your previous AVD, So you wouldn't face this problem anymore in the future.

Answer (score -2):

You have to uncheck the hardware keyboard present option. It would then be enabled. So the option would be

```
Display a skin with hardware controls - true
Hardware keyboard present - false
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your AVD settings ?

Comment: this is sceershot of my avd setting