# D-pad doesn't work on popup menu

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, d-pad

I am writing an app for a GoogleTV, my user will be using a remote control to navigate across the app. I found out that D-pad doesn't work on spinner's pop up. 
After some time of digging the problem, I have also realize that the D-pad navigation doesn't work on popup menu. Which spinner is using it, as well as actionbar overflow menu.

So my question is, Is there a way to solve that d-pad navigation problem?
I use android remote downloaded from android market, installed on phone as a remote and nexus 10 as a TV.

popupMenu : android.widget.PopupMenu;

spinner : android.widget.Spinner;

[android remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tournesol.tabletremote)

screenshot of popup

[image]

Comment: you this ,It may help :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561251/dpad-is-disabled-in-emulator

Comment: The problem is in a different case. Anyway, I have already solve it by  creating custom popup window by extending PopupWindow class.