# DPAD is disable in my AVD(keyboard)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to set up your own virtual keyboard
I've tried all the solutions
Please help me.
in particular i read this answer
[D'pad Is disabled in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561251/dpad-is-disabled-in-emulator)
:(

please see this image
http://upload7.ir/images/03852186887702819767.png

I do not want create custom keyboard. just i want have virtual keyboard in AVD

**PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO IMAGE AND LINK SENT**

Comment: can you be clear about what you want. Do you want a custom keyboard?

Comment: yes, i want custom keyboard.in place that show in pic

Comment: PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO IMAGE THAT SENT

Comment: You can find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561251/dpad-is-disabled-in-emulator

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following links:

- [android emulator keyboard not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812064/android-emulator-keyboard-not-displaying)
- [avd hardware buttons not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100251/avd-hardware-buttons-not-enabled)

Comment: I do not want create custom keyboard. just i want have virtual keyboard in AVD

Comment: i have edited my answer. please check and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Hey if you have got your answer please accept the answer so that others can get a help.

Comment: Still the same problem??

Comment: yes but now i can find ~android-->config.ini-->hw.dpda=no but when i change it to YES i have not any event in AVD. MY GOOOOD Please Help meeeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

When creating new device using avd, choose create new profile instead of importing existing ones and enables d-pad input in profile.

AVD -> create virtual device -> new hardware profile -> input -> navigation style 
 choose D-Pad.

Comment: after wasting 2 hours on net, i tried to do myself and then found this solution, it will work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of problem editting different file.

```
Go to C:\Users\YourUserName\.android\avd\YourAVDName
Edit the hardware-gemu.ini file.
Change hw.dPad = no or hw.dPad = false like hw.dPad = yes and save the file.
After you restart the AVD, Dpad is enabled.
```